# Куда направлять пользователей из Черного списка?

Tags: php, хостинг, защита

Хотелось бы сразу получить ответ на такие под вопросы:

1. Подскажите, если на хостинге есть некий фильтр по IP адресам куда в нем отправляются пользователи которые пришли с этих адресов?
2. Получают ли они информацию с сайта который размещен на хостинге?
3. Есть ли практика в создании отдельных страниц (что-то по типу страницы 404) для таких пользователей?
4. Будет ли хостинг блокировать DDoS-атаку если адреса этих пользователей поместить в такой black list?

Comment: *куда в нем отправляються пользователи которые пришли с этих адресов?* По вкусу... например, в 403.

Comment: Это где-то регламентировано? По сути они в первих пакетах передачи, там где они отсилают свой IP сравнивают его с black list на хостинге? насколько глубоко они "видят" сайт?

Comment: *Это где-то регламентировано?* Конечно, нет... фильтрация по IP - это твоя личная инициатива, вот и зюкайся с ней дальше так же самостоятельно. А 403 - это просто по смыслу подходит. Какая-никакая, а всё логика...